# git commit fails for directory name that includes whitespace character on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I am working on a git versioned software project on Microsoft Windows 10. The tool in use is Git-Bash. From one day to the other I was not able to commit a staged directory, that contains a whitespace character in its path name, i.e., "Automatisierte Validierung/".

The error message git throws is

```
Fixing whitespace in Automatisierte
sed: can't read Automatisierte: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Automatisierte: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Automatisierte: No such file or directory
fatal: pathspec 'Automatisierte' did not match any files
Fixing whitespace in Validierung/Dokumentation/Dokumentation
sed: can't read Validierung/Dokumentation/Dokumentation: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Validierung/Dokumentation/Dokumentation: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Validierung/Dokumentation/Dokumentation: No such file or directory
fatal: pathspec 'Validierung/Dokumentation/Dokumentation' did not match any files
Fixing whitespace in Automatisierte
sed: can't read Automatisierte: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Automatisierte: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Automatisierte: No such file or directory
fatal: pathspec 'Automatisierte' did not match any files
Fixing whitespace in Validierung.Rmd
sed: can't read Validierung.Rmd: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Validierung.Rmd: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Validierung.Rmd: No such file or directory
fatal: pathspec 'Validierung.Rmd' did not match any files
```

Appearantly, git thinks I want to commit two distinct files. A first one, that is named "Automatisierte" and the other one "Validierung". I never came across such an issue since the last 3 years versioning with git.

Any suggestions?

Comment: this isn't a git error, but a [tag:sed] error. Please take a moment and review your question and your tags.

Comment: What command did you type in?

Answer (score 0):

You should add character \ to path name.

Ex:

"Automatisierte\ Validierung/"

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, as mentioned by **Daemon Painter** independent of git. The problem has been a pre-commit file in my home directory `~/.githooks/pre-commit`, that manipulates files bevor the are commited (as the name *pre-commit* suggests).

The manipulation is basically done with **sed**. I temporarily removed this file and the subsequent commit came out successfully.

Thank you for your valuable help,

Philipp